# How to load yaml files in chunks?

Tags: python, yaml, generator

I'm using PyYaml to load data with yaml.load and/or yaml.safe_load, but the performance is really poor as they load the whole file and those are large.

Is there a way (other function/lib/parameter) with which I can load the yaml file in chunks (e.g. one dict an iter) or as a generator for that?